# simple if else or preg_match expression

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I have an example.php form when posted to perl script example.pl which responds either this

```
<!-- comments disabled -->
```

or this

```
<!-- comments enabled -->
```

The above response is stored in php get request in `$commentstatus` variable

Response may be a multiline or single line !

How to build an expression or verify the response using php preg_match or a normal validation for if else condition in php?

Comment: trim() then if (content == expectedcontent)

Comment: How about simply, `if (preg_match('/<!-- comments enabled -->/', $commentstatus)){` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the presence of a string, within a string with [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos).

So the actual code would be:

```
<?php
if (strpos($commentstatus, "<!-- comments disabled -->") !== false)
{
}
elseif(strpos($commentstatus, "<!-- comments disabled -->") !== false)
{
}
```

Comment: Response may be in a single line or in multiline after <!-- so exact pattern may not match

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying?

Comment: @BetaCoder: are saying that the response can be something like this: `<!--\ncomments\ndisabled -->` ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes thats exactly the perl response may generate - line breaks or whitespaces,hence asking for the efficient solution

Answer (score 1):

```php
function commentsEnabled($str){
    preg_match_all('/^.*?<!--\s*comments\s+(en|dis)abled\s*-->.*$/m', $str, $m);
    return !count($m[1]) ? null : array_pop($m[1]) == 'en';
}
```

[**demo**](http://ideone.com/uot3xU)

[image]

[**enlarge image**](http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5E.*%3F%3C!--%5Cs*comments%5Cs%2B(en%7Cdis)abled%5Cs*--%3E.*%24%2Fm)

Comment: I should note that it searches for ***all*** matches and takes the *"status"* from the last one it found.

Comment: Cant Resist but +1 for the image and clear explanation with a link

Answer (score 1):

Credits to @lbu for the SIMPLEST solution who commented under the Op

This works excellently and is the easiest

```
$content= trim($commentstatus);

if ($content == "<!--commentsdisabled-->"){

 print "Dear User Comments are disabled for your access";

}else if($content == "<!--commentsenabled-->"){

print "Dear User Comment added to blog post entry";

}else{

 print "You are Banned for Spamming";

}
```

Comment: I don't think this code deals with possible line breaks!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The Fact is the browser rendering adds the styling in the sourcecode as a linebreak

Comment: trim is only supposed to remove white space (or specified characters) from the beginning and end of strings? This is clearly noted in the documentation of the trim() function. Unless i'm missing something, I don't see how this is working for the solution, but hey, if it works, it works.

Answer (score 1):

@degenerate
"Learn how to read the PHP documentation," - rude and assumptious

But your code works, even for line breaks read in from a file.

```
    if (preg_match('@enabled@', $commentstatus)){
      // Enabled code
    }else{
      // Everything else code
    }
```

I don't know how it works, because the documentation you linked says to use the 's' switch :

*"The s tells the code NOT TO stop searching when it encounters \n (line break)"*

This works is with `preg_match_all` & `preg_match` !!

It's a plus 1 even with the ending snark!

Not sure what @BetaCoder is on about, but it's obviously *not* a question.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you are simply asking this?

```
if (preg_match('@enabled@', $commentstatus)){
    // Enabled code
}else{
    // Everything else code
}
```

Learn how to read the PHP documentation, please:
https://www.php.net/preg_match

Comment: Thats a html underlying comment not a statement or boolen response

Comment: What do you mean? Your question doesn't make sense.